# How to get camcorder record button press event on computer?

Tags: directshow, video-capture, video-recording, pins

I made a desktop application to take video from the camcorder and saves it on my computer. But the only problem is that I want that when I press record button on the camcorder it will automatically start recording the video on my computer and when I again press the record button on the camcorder the recording on my computer should automatically stop.

I am using this carmcorder :Sony HandyCam dcr-vx2100
Connection : FireWire

Comment: Is the question how to auto-launch your recording app or how to make the already-running recording app notice that the video stream started? For the latter, what do the video stream recording API docs say? For the former, you might need a background task that polls for camera connection.

Comment: The video streaming from the video camera is happening. And when I press start record from the software itself then it is working fine. But I want to get the event of button press on the camcorder asking my app to start recording and stop it.

Comment: Do you want the camcorder start-button to launch your app? Or do you want it to make your already-running app start recording?

Comment: I want it to make my already-running app start recording.

Comment: OK. That should be easier. Have you looked in the API docs? Where are they? What is the name of the API you use to read the video data? To venture a guess, there should either be a way for the program to listen for a notification when the video stream begins, or a way to test if the video is streaming in (which you could periodically test), or both.

Comment: I am not getting any solution. Can you help me with this sir.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these APIs and you haven't identified what APIs they are. How did you go about writing the application to capture the video stream? Where is the documentation? Do look there.